# Background (sky/terrain) of a viewshed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, grass-gis, viewshed, visibility

Is it possible to determine whether a point feature of a particular height would be backed by sky or by terrain?

I've done the viewsheed analysis of a wind turbine. Now I would like to make a raster map representing the background (sky/terrain) from each cell of the viewshed.

Comment: You essentially need to compare the horizon angle (in the direction of the windmill) to the top-of-windmill angle. I am not aware of an existing tool for this -- how good are you at scripting?

Comment: You say you've done a viewshed analysis - using 3D Analyst? If so, have you looked at the Sight Line or Skyline tools?

Comment: The workflow at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/58779 does the hard part of the computation @Erica suggests. At each cell of the grid you will compute the bearing and azimuth toward the turbine.  Those two coordinates will locate a point in the "land-sky" map shown at the beginning of that answer. Where that point is determines whether the turbine is backed up by land or sky.

Comment: @whuber That will tell you whether a given point on the landscape is sky or land *from the windmill's perspective* -- I understand the question here as "is the windmill above the horizon from each vantage point in the surrounding landscape"?

Comment: @Erica Draw a picture to represent the terrain transected by the line through a grid cell and the turbine. Let the x-axis show location along the line and the y-axis, elevation. Post two points representing the cell's center and the top of the turbine. On the side opposite the turbine from the cell, draw a vertical line segment representing the land beneath the horizon. Draw a ray from the cell towards the turbine and extend it until it intersects or rises over that line segment. Finally, draw a ray from the turbine to the top of the segment (the horizon). Compare angles and draw conclusions.

Comment: Oh, I see. So if the angle to groundpoint is less than the angle to horizonpoint from the windmill's perspective, the horizon is what's visible; if greater, sky is what's visible. Easier than the way I'd been figuring it out in my head :) Thanks!